# how to create regex expression

Tags: regex

I have 2 kinds of string one with "Message:" and "Priority:" and other's without it.

```
string str1 = [AE][1W] Message:test mesage Priority:Info
string str2 = test message
```

I would like to prepare Regex expression to check the existence of "Message:" and "Priority:" in string.

Below is not working,

```
(Message:[A-Za-z]\w+ Priority:[A-Za-z])\w+
```

what it should be?

Comment: `\w` will only catch *word* characters, not whitespace, so it'll find `test` and then stop matching. Can you please tell us more about the rules for what you want to match and what shouldn't match? If not, try simply replacing `\w+` with `.+`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your regex to:

```
(Message:[A-Za-z]+ \w+ Priority:[A-Za-z])\w+
```

to make it work. However I'd write it like:

```
Message:(\w+[ ]?)+Priority:(\w+[ ]?)+
```

So that there could be more than 1 word after `Message` or `Priority`.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to  [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39749990/6588087)

```
string str = "[AE][1W] Message:test message Priority:Info Time:Sep 22 2016  11:59PM Tag:/System Compon/  Source:CONSOLE STATION  IsAck:1 IsRtn:0 IsNew:1";
```

Try this:

```
Message:([\w\s]+)Priority:([\w\s]+)Time:([\w\s:]+)Tag:([/\w\s]+)Source:([\w\s]+)IsAck:([\w\s]+)IsRtn:([\w\s]+)IsNew:([\w\s]+)
```

below might be even better:

```
Message:([\w\s]+)Priority:([\w\s]+)Time:([\w\s:]+)Tag:([/\w\s]+)Source:([\w\s]+)IsAck:(\d) IsRtn:(\d) IsNew:(\d)
```